# Non-positive occurrence due to polymorphic function

Tags: coq, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to define a data type with a constructor that takes a list, and include propositions about this list.

This works fine:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive Foo :=  MkFoo : list Foo -> Foo.
```

And so does this:

```
Inductive Foo :=  MkFoo : forall (l : list Foo), Foo.
```

But this fails

```
Inductive Foo :=  MkFoo : forall (l : list Foo), l <> [] -> Foo.
```

with

> ```
> Non strictly positive occurrence of "Foo"
> in "forall l : list Foo, l <> [] -> Foo".
> ```

I assume that this is because `[]` is actually `@nil Foo` and Coq does not like this occurrence of `Foo`.

I am currently working my way around it using vector, like so

```
Require Import Coq.Vectors.Vector.

Inductive Foo :=  MkFoo : forall n (l : Vector.t Foo n), n <> 0 -> Foo.
```

but the complications that arise due to the use of dependent data structures in Coq make me wonder:

Is there a way I can use plain lists in `MkFoo` and still include propositions about that list?

Comment: It sounds like your type is not inhabited: there is no way of producing a base case. Perhaps your actual use case is more involved?

Comment: **Coq should allow me to write my empty types however I want!**

Comment: But yes, the real case has more constructors… :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there isn't a way of including that constraint directly in the definition, unfortunately.  I see two paths forward:

1. Change the definition of `mkFoo` so that it takes the head of the list as an additional argument:

   ```
   mkFoo : Foo -> list Foo -> Foo
   ```
2. Define `Foo` without any restrictions, and define a separate well-formedness predicate:

   ```
   Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

   Inductive Foo := mkFoo : list Foo -> Foo.

   Definition isEmpty {T : Type} (x : list T) :=
     match x with
     | nil => true
     | _   => false
     end.

   Fixpoint wfFoo (x : Foo) : Foo :=
     match x with
     | mkFoo xs => negb (isEmpty xs) && forallb wfFoo xs
     end.
   ```

   You can then show that all the functions on `Foo` that you care about respect `wfFoo`.  It is also possible to use subset types to pack members of `Foo` with proofs of `wfFoo`, guaranteeing that clients of `Foo` never have to touch ill-formed elements.  Since `wfFoo` is defined as a boolean property, the equation `wfFoo x = true` is proof-irrelevant, which guarantees that the type `{ x : Foo | wfFoo x = true }` is well-behaved.  The [Mathematical Components library](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp) provides good support for this kind of construction.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative negative answer :-)